# grep line which contains only one word (ignore white space) after pattern is matched

Tags: linux, grep

Hi I want to grep only one word which is after matching pattern.

Example

(1)  (xyz abc or def)

(2)  (xyz pqr)

```
  If my matching pattern is xyz then  o/p should (xyz pqr).

   I want to grep line which contains only one word (ignore white space) after pattern is matched.

  So how can I do?
```

---Vishal

Comment: [edit] your post and clearly indicate what is a sample input data and its desired output. Currently it is quite unclear because you are formatting quite strangely

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
grep '\bxyz\s*\w*)$' file
```

if the word after pattern is required, use `'\bxyz\s*\w\+)$'`

with your example:

```
kent$  cat f
(xyz abc or def)

(xyz   pqr)
LsyHP 12:46:30 /tmp/test
kent$  grep '\bxyz\s*\w\+)$' f
(xyz   pqr)
```

*updated the answer with brackets.*

Comment: In my pattern also both bracket()